# Agregar headers de cloudfront de localización

Tags: aws, headers

Tengo una web nextjs en amplify y una distribucion de cloutfront asociado a ella,
por defecto esta cloudfront-viewer-country y muestra el codigo de mi país, agregue los demás pero no aparecen,¿ Hay que hacer algo mas?, solo requiero el codigo del pais y las coordenadas(sin activar el gps), pensaba usar ubicación por ip, pero al hacer un log del req que dan getServerSideProps de next, encontré cloudfront-viewer-country
[image: AWS Cloudfront]
[image: headers]

Comment: estás hablando de la petición que le llega a amplify o de la respuesta que recibe el cliente?

Comment: @eferion La que recibe el cliente

Comment: Pues entonces esto no te va a funcionar. Lo que tu estás configurando ahí es información que va en el "request", es decir, lo que va a recibir amplify. Otra cosa es que en amplify recabes esa información y se la envies al cliente